# Rails create mapping to wrong route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have a Rails form to create a profile for a store.  Initially, I had handled the routing thusly `resources :stores` and all was well.  However, I wanted to divide my resources for stores between an admin scope and a 'public' scope.  Once I did this, the form submission stopped working, passing me the error 'No route matches [POST] "/admin/stores"'.  I'm not clear on why this is happening, since I thought I divided my resources appropriately...

```
scope "/admin" do
    resources :stores, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
end

resources :stores, only: [:new, :create]
```

Here are the controller actions...

```
def new
    @store = current_user.stores.new
    @store.build_address
    @storeType = StoreType.all
end

def create
    @store = current_user.stores.new(store_params)

    if @store.save
        flash[:notice] = "New store created"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        #ERROR STUFF
    end
end
```

One thing that I noticed in the Rails route info is that the POST action for create gets lumped into the store_path with all of the other /admin prefixed resources

```
stores_path 
   GET  /admin/stores(.:format) stores#index
edit_store_path 
   GET  /admin/stores/:id/edit(.:format)    stores#edit
store_path
   PATCH    /admin/stores/:id(.:format) stores#update
   PUT  /admin/stores/:id(.:format) stores#update
   DELETE   /admin/stores/:id(.:format) stores#destroy
   POST /stores(.:format)   stores#create
new_store_path
   GET  /stores/new(.:format)   stores#new
```

I'm not sure I understand why this is happening, any help would be greatly appreciated.  Why is the form trying to post to an admin route when I put the :new and :create actions in the 'public' route?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does the form just use `form_for(@store)`?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; you're asking why the `store_path` for `create` is listed under the other `store_path` HTTP methods? I mean, the URL is right, it's a `store_path`, and everything seems correct.

Comment: It's not posting to an admin route, it *shows* you the route it'll post to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`POST` is routed to the create action, you specifically stated which actions you wanted leaving out the `create` action on the `resources` call

change it to this and it should work

```
scope "/admin" do
    resources :stores, only: [:index, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
end
```

If you want to use a route outside your current namespace (admin) you need to pass the `url: store_path` option to the form helper and also specify the `method: :post` option.